# What's the correct use of whitespace for Go arrays?

Tags: arrays, go

It's possible to do the following in Go when initialising an array:

```
var hp = [3]string{"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"}   // 1
var hp = [3]string {"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"}  // 2
var hp = [3] string{"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"}  // 3
var hp = [3] string {"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"} // 4
```

4 looks the neatest to me, but 1 is what I've seen more commonly. It seems that Go doesn't mind whitespace around tokens in the same way as C and C++ though. What's the correct, canonical or "Go-like" way to initialise an array? Is there an equivalent to Python's "PEP" style guides for GoLang?

Comment: Let it be handled by [`gofmt`](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/). (it's 1 btw)

Comment: What does `go fmt` say?

Comment: The Go tool comes with a "universally" accepted formatter. Format your source with that, whatever is the output, it'll be accepted by the Go community. Hint: it'll format to the first version.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard of go fmt. Turns out the playground has a button which does it for me. As @icza says, it defaults to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned, this style is the "correct" one:

```
var hp = [3]string{"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"}
```

as it is what is produced by `gofmt`. If it bothers you to think about the
different space options, you can just use a type instead:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type cast [3]string

func main() {
   hp := cast{"Harry", "Ron", "Hermione"}
   fmt.Println(hp)
}
```

https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt